# Error installing scalate on osx

Tags: macos, scalate

Got below error when installing scalate on OSX Yosemite by following http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/installing.html

```
brew install scalate
Error: No available formula for scalate
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
brew update
brew tap --repair && brew tap homebrew/science
brew install octave
```